# Solve the equation $x^2+x+9\equiv 0\pmod {63}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruence-relations

Solve the equation $x^2+x+9\equiv 0\pmod {63}$

Quadratic equation $x^2+x+9=0$ can't be factorized (with integer roots).

Also, $63$ is not a prime, and I have checked the method of *completing the square*.

What method to use for this congruence relation?

Comment: Solve $4x^2+4x+36\equiv 0\pmod{63}$, or equivalently $(2x+1)^2\equiv -35\equiv 28$\pmod{63}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$63 = 9 \times 7$.  Do it mod $9$ and mod $7$ (these are small enough that you can look at each case individually), then put the results together with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Is it necessary to factorize $9=3\cdot 3$ and look three equations (two with mod $3$)?

Comment: No, it's quite easy to do mod $9$ directly.  The equation simplifies to $x (x+1) \equiv 0 \mod 9$.